# Heroku crashes after first deploy of app war

Tags: grails, heroku, deployment

I've been working with Heroku for a while but recently I made a deploy and the server crashes after the boot process, I thought it were the changes i made on my app but it also crashed when i did a rollback to an stable version. Also I have other apps in Heroku but they're works well.

Here is the log I get from Heroku:

```
2017-11-02T16:28:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user jrocha@tequilasoft.mx
2017-11-02T16:29:08.194071+00:00 app[api]: Deploy by user jrocha@tequilasoft.mx
2017-11-02T16:29:08.194071+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user jrocha@tequilasoft.mx
2017-11-02T16:28:51.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-11-02T16:29:13.788934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-11-02T16:29:13.789643+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-11-02T16:29:14.634283+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-11-02T16:29:15.859033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-11-02T16:29:18.152572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -jar webapp-runner.jar ${WEBAPP_RUNNER_OPTS} --port 38177 ./Repositorios/projectsgo/moneystartdev/web/app/build/libs/app-1.2.6.war`
2017-11-02T16:29:19.202807+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-11-02T16:29:19.205864+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2017-11-02T16:29:19.887554+00:00 app[web.1]: Expanding app-1.2.6.war into /app/target/tomcat.38177/webapps/expanded
2017-11-02T16:29:19.887606+00:00 app[web.1]: Adding Context  for /app/target/tomcat.38177/webapps/expanded
2017-11-02T16:29:20.142569+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
2017-11-02T16:29:20.142576+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-38177"]
2017-11-02T16:29:20.170104+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-11-02T16:29:20.166867+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:20 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
2017-11-02T16:29:20.166871+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017-11-02T16:29:20.170103+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
2017-11-02T16:29:20.171005+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
2017-11-02T16:29:20.171007+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-11-02T16:29:20.227889+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-11-02T16:29:20.399096+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
2017-11-02T16:29:20.399104+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: No global web.xml found
2017-11-02T16:29:24.382001+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:24 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
2017-11-02T16:29:24.382017+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-11-02T16:29:25.980976+00:00 app[web.1]: Nov 02, 2017 4:29:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
2017-11-02T16:29:25.980984+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
2017-11-02T16:29:30.453446+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:30.453468+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuring Spring Security Core ...
2017-11-02T16:29:30.548792+00:00 app[web.1]: ... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2017-11-02T16:29:30.548803+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:30.632911+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:30.632914+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuring Spring Security REST 2.0.0.M2...
2017-11-02T16:29:30.665305+00:00 app[web.1]: ... finished configuring Spring Security REST
2017-11-02T16:29:30.665311+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:30.666267+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... with GORM support
2017-11-02T16:29:31.818325+00:00 app[web.1]: Thu Nov 02 16:29:31 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-11-02T16:29:32.108887+00:00 app[web.1]: Thu Nov 02 16:29:32 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-11-02T16:29:32.127550+00:00 app[web.1]: Thu Nov 02 16:29:32 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-11-02T16:29:32.143749+00:00 app[web.1]: Thu Nov 02 16:29:32 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-11-02T16:29:32.162251+00:00 app[web.1]: Thu Nov 02 16:29:32 UTC 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492539+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-11-02 16:29:43.487 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492549+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492550+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492551+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.AbstractTypeDescriptor.extractHashCode(AbstractTypeDescriptor.java:65)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492552+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:185)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492553+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.getHashCode(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:189)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492556+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getHashCode(EntityType.java:355)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492557+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:241)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492557+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.generateHashCode(EntityKey.java:59)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492558+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityKey.<init>(EntityKey.java:54)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492559+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.generateEntityKey(AbstractSessionImpl.java:338)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.getDatabaseSnapshot(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:308)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:238)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492561+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:499)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492562+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:83)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492562+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492563+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.support.ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.onSaveOrUpdate(ClosureEventTriggeringInterceptor.java:126)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492564+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:651)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492565+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:643)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492565+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:638)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492566+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi$_performSave_closure3.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:243)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492567+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492568+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492570+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492570+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492571+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492572+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492572+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492573+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConvertedClosure.invokeCustom(ConvertedClosure.java:54)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492574+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ConversionHandler.invoke(ConversionHandler.java:124)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492575+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.doInHibernate(Unknown Source)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492576+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:298)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492576+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:242)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492577+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:116)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492577+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.performSave(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:242)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492578+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:159)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492579+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:118)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492580+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:98)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492580+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.app.UserRole.save(UserRole.groovy)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492581+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.app.UserRole.save(UserRole.groovy)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492582+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492582+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492583+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492584+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492584+00:00 app[web.1]:    at app.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:155)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492591+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492592+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492593+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492594+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492595+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492596+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492596+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492597+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492598+00:00 app[web.1]:    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492598+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:535)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492599+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:528)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492600+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:504)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492603+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:261)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492604+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492605+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492605+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492606+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492607+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492608+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492608+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492609+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492610+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492611+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492611+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492612+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492613+00:00 app[web.1]:    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492614+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492615+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492615+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492616+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492617+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492618+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492619+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492620+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492621+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492622+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492622+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.492623+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-02T16:29:43.515937+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516002+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516038+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516065+00:00 app[web.1]:    at webapp.runner.launch.Main.main(Main.java:274)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516151+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516173+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516201+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516220+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516241+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 2 more
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516298+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516331+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516334+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516353+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516375+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 4 more
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516427+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516473+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516504+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516521+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
2017-11-02T16:29:43.516538+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 6 more
2017-11-02T16:29:43.952804+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

It seems like the problem is in the application.yml:

```
dataSource:
    dbCreate: update
    url : jdbc:mysql://y2w3wxldca8enczv.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username : mydbusername
    password : mydbpassword
    properties:
        jmxEnabled: true
        initialSize: 5
        maxActive: 50
        minIdle: 5
        maxIdle: 25
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
        defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

I removed this configurations and leave the code by default:

```
dataSource:
    dbCreate: create-drop
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

With this the app boots well but now I have no connection to my database.

Comment: Looks like a problem interacting with the database. Have you run migrations to create the db schema?

Comment: you're right, I try without connection to the database and the app deployed well.